# No data read from XML source with inline schema by SSIS

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, ssis

I have an SSIS project that calls a web service and returns the data in the form of an xml document.  Next, I need to parse that xml in a data flow task and load it into a sql server database.

The xml file has an inline schema and contains plenty of data.  In my XML Source in the data flow, I select "inline schema" and all of the columns are listed correctly.  Everything seems fine up to this point.

However, when I execute the package, no data is being loaded from the xml source and no errors are thrown.  The output message says "'OLE DB Destination wrote 0 rows'".  My dataview does not show any data being piped out of the xml source, and I have eliminated my OLE DB destination as the source of my troubles by testing with a simple flat file as my destination (same problem, no data is written and no errors are thrown).

Below is an excerpt from my xml source with an inline schema, which is created by my web service task.  I would appreciate any and all help troubleshooting this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="UPDATEDDEPT">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="DEPT_ID" type="xs:long" />
            <xs:element name="PARENT_ID" type="xs:long" />
            <xs:element name="DEPT_NAME">
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:maxLength value="30" />
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="DEPTH" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="LINEAGE">
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:maxLength value="150" />
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="PRODUCTCOUNT" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="MARKETLEADER" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="PROFITBUILDER" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="NEWITEM" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="PALLET" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="LASTUPDATED" type="xs:dateTime" />
            <xs:element name="STATUS" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet>
  <UPDATEDDEPT diffgr:id="UPDATEDDEPT1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
    <DEPT_ID>1010100000000000000</DEPT_ID>
    <PARENT_ID>1000000000000000000</PARENT_ID>
    <DEPT_NAME>STRIKING AND CUTTING TOOLS    </DEPT_NAME>
    <DEPTH>1</DEPTH>
    <LINEAGE>/1000000000000000000/1010100000000000000/</LINEAGE>
    <PRODUCTCOUNT>1054</PRODUCTCOUNT>
    <MARKETLEADER>1</MARKETLEADER>
    <PROFITBUILDER>2</PROFITBUILDER>
    <NEWITEM>8</NEWITEM>
    <PALLET>0</PALLET>
    <LASTUPDATED>2013-02-04T05:38:57.437-05:00</LASTUPDATED>
    <STATUS>1</STATUS>
  </UPDATEDDEPT>
  <UPDATEDDEPT diffgr:id="UPDATEDDEPT2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
    <DEPT_ID>7070570565000000000</DEPT_ID>
    <PARENT_ID>7070500000000000000</PARENT_ID>
    <DEPT_NAME>KNIVES &amp; ACCESS               </DEPT_NAME>
    <DEPTH>2</DEPTH>
    <LINEAGE>/7000000000000000000/7070500000000000000/7070570565000000000/</LINEAGE>
    <PRODUCTCOUNT>176</PRODUCTCOUNT>
    <MARKETLEADER>0</MARKETLEADER>
    <PROFITBUILDER>0</PROFITBUILDER>
    <NEWITEM>2</NEWITEM>
    <PALLET>0</PALLET>
    <LASTUPDATED>2013-02-04T05:38:59.823-05:00</LASTUPDATED>
    <STATUS>1</STATUS>
  </UPDATEDDEPT>
 </NewDataSet>
 </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kyle, are you still monitoring this?
This article may shed some light 
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/579439/ssis-xmlsource-xsd-integer-converts-incorrectly-in-xml-source

The XML source i am trying to read in comes from a VFP 9 table and has XSD inline. Any of the obviously integer attributes like keys are specified as type="decimal" in the XSD. VFP doesn't have an integer type. It's blanket type is Numeric. I've tried both external, inline and generated versions of XSD. There is the option xml integer mapping in XML source, which can bet set int32 or decimal but i don't understand its function.

Anyway, If i attempt to modify in the XSD say, the decimal fields to integer(or long) key fields that i know are definitely integers, then XML source read buggers up. It generates no errors and gives green ticks like a kindergarten teacher on acid. On the other hand, if I let the Original inline XSD have it's way, with the decimal fields intact, it works. Thats a 200M file with XML structured as table. About 7 seconds to import. Oh yes, a memo field is tacked on at the end as varchar(4000)

I found my happiest path is to get the SQL destination to generate my table, load it and then CONVERT attributes to another table with more apt types.

Hope this helps

Addendum
A Data Conversion process works nicely between xml source and sql destination. So rewrite all the Int types in XSD to decimal, reload XSD in xml source, then convert back to int in Data Conversion.